# Newsstand auto-renewable or free In-App

Tags: newsstand-kit, auto-renewing

I have created one app and its live on app store.

Now, I want to enable this app as Newsstand.

I read below for Newsstand:

"Newsstand apps must offer at least one auto-renewable or free In-App Purchase subscription."

Inside app, it will read XML file from server, and if new issues Tag will be added in XML then it will ask to user for download new issue.

Means, I am managing the all new issues from my server side through XML. (Not through auto-renewable or free In-App of Apple).

But I have added key of Newsstand so that app will be displayed as Newsstand.

Is it ok? Will Apple approve my app?

Because I am not using "auto-renewable or free In-App". And manage issues from XML on server side.

Please let me provide your feedback and also let me know what to do for "auto-renewable or free In-App".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any subscription(free/paid) which you have to create in iTunes, Apple will not approve your Newsstand app, for sure. 
Idea is that users can subscribe and your app can download new issues automatically in bachround using Newsstand push notification. Let me know and i will write answer in more detail ( right now on Phone)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. As per your answer, do we have to integrate Background download also? Regarding subscription, we will just add on button for subscription. And without subscription, user can also download our new issues. Because subscription is free. Is it ok? Please share your idea.

Comment: yes, you need to provide button for subscription. Though B/G download is not a hard requirement to get your app approve. But Newsstand users would expect this from your app. For users subscription purchase is not necessary to download content. They can download content (paid or free, no matter) w/o subscription also.